# Flask-WTFform: Flash does not display errors

Tags: python, flask, wtforms

I'm trying to flash WTForm validation errors. I found [this snippet](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/12/) and slightly modified it:

```
 def flash_errors(form):
    """Flashes form errors"""
    for field, errors in form.errors.items():
        for error in errors:
            flash(u"Error in the %s field - %s" % (
                getattr(form, field).label.text,
                error
            ), 'error')
```

Here is one of my form classes:

```
class ContactForm(Form):
    """Contact form"""
    # pylint: disable=W0232
    # pylint: disable=R0903
    name = TextField(label="Name", validators=[Length(max=35), Required()])
    email = EmailField(label="Email address",
                       validators=[Length(min=6, max=120), Email()])
    message = TextAreaField(label="Message",
                            validators=[Length(max=1000), Required()])
    recaptcha = RecaptchaField()
```

And view:

```
@app.route("/contact/", methods=("GET", "POST"))
def contact():
    """Contact view"""
    form = ContactForm()
    flash_errors(form)
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        sender = "%s <%s>" % (form.name.data, form.email.data)
        subject = "Message from %s" % form.name.data
        message = form.message.data
        body = render_template('emails/contact.html', sender=sender,
                               message=message)
        email_admin(subject, body)
        flash("Your message has been sent. Thank you!", "success")

    return render_template("contact.html",
                           form=form)
```

However, no errors are flashed upon validation failures. I know my forms and templates work fine, because my success message flashes when the data is valid. What is wrong?

Comment: That `flash_errors` function is awesome!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**There are no errors yet because you haven't processed the form yet**

Try putting the `flash_errors` on the `else` of the `validate_on_submit` method

```
@app.route("/contact/", methods=("GET", "POST"))
def contact():
    """Contact view"""
    form = ContactForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        sender = "%s <%s>" % (form.name.data, form.email.data)
        subject = "Message from %s" % form.name.data
        message = form.message.data
        body = render_template('emails/contact.html', sender=sender,
                               message=message)
        email_admin(subject, body)
        flash("Your message has been sent. Thank you!", "success")
    else:
        flash_errors(form)

    return render_template("contact.html",
                       form=form)
```

Comment: I think sometimes just typing out the questions helps you to start thinking about the problem differently or more clearly.

Comment: I vote up for your concise statement there i_4_got. I just have that same experience myself, here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19152471/what-is-the-technique-of-presenting-again-form-which-contains-error

Comment: Personally, I'm stoked 'bout your brain haze, cuz I just discovered a new way to debug Flask! WOOT!